# My Wordpress site creating the issue pixelated in upload jpg file?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

From two days i am shocking and have surprize, if upload the jpg image in wordpress site via
media then its make my image pixelated.  Even image fine.  If i upload png image then its working fine.  But any jpg upload in correct format but when see in browser then its come pixelated and blur check below link, first time you see this fine but when you refresh then you see its come blurred.

http://www.edarabia.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/prince-andrew-visits-british-school-al-khubairat2.jpg

IF you check here then its show fine

http://www.edarabia.com/102810/prince-andrew-visits-british-school-al-khubairat/

Even i done all plugin setting default restore and done many experiment but this problem not solved.

Thanks

Comment: its jpg with 1% quality. First step is to disable all plugin and test, if it works, enable plugins 1 by 1 and you will find problem.

Answer (score 0):

General answer to "my Wordpress site has issue":

1. disable plugins - if problem gone, enable plugins one by and and test again.
2. check functions.php for extra functionality - try to remove all filters here.
3. test with some default theme. IF problem solved - issue was on theme.